# How to change a line in a file using SED properly?

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed

I'm trying to use bash's SED command in OS X and failing.

I need to change this line `#"phpunit/phpunit:3.7.*",` to the same but without the `#` (so like this `"phpunit/phpunit:3.7.*",` in my file.

What is the best way to do that in sed?

I tried this: `sed -i -e "s/#\"phpunit/phpunit:3.7.*\",/\"phpunit/phpunit:3.7.*\"," file.txt`

but that didn't work :(

Comment: "didn't work" is very rarely a good description of a problem: Did it do nothing? Did it change too much? Did you get any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

I can see an obvious error, that you use the substitution separator character (the slash) inside the regular expression part. You must escape it, like:

```
sed -e "s/#\"phpunit\/phpunit:3.7.*\",/\"phpunit\/phpunit:3.7.*\",/" file.txt
```

An improvement could be to group what you want to keep, like:

```
sed -e "s/#\(\"phpunit\/phpunit:3.7.*\",\)/\1/" file.txt
```

Both solutions yield:

```
"phpunit/phpunit:3.7.*",
```

I don't use `OS X`, so I omitted the `-i` switch. In `linux` is enought `-i` with an space following it, but in your system I think you must provide a blank string, like: `-i''` but not sure, so test this part.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use something like

```
sed 's/#//' file.txt
```

And if you need more specificty then

```
sed 's/#"php/"php/' file.txt
```

Comment: This works but doesn't output to the file, it dumps it into the console. How can I make these output to my file instead of the console?

Comment: I got it working with this: `sed -i '' 's/#"phpunit/"phpunit/' file.txt`

Comment: In the future you should probably use -i.bak flag, which will create a backup just in case the inlining fails.  But otherwise yea, that'll do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat input
#"phpunit/phpunit:3.7.*",
```

Some serious back-slashing later, due to the special characters `*`, `.` and `/`:

```
$ sed  's/#"phpunit\/phpunit:3\.7\.\*",/"phpunit\/phpunit:3\.7\.\*",/' input
"phpunit/phpunit:3.7.*",
```